# RunTestCase Reference is missing in SoapUI when import others Suite?

Tags: soapui

we have the following Structure for the Project in SoapUI Restful Automation

```
SuiteName1: ReusableComponent
SuiteName2:CustomerManagement (By RunTestCase option, calling the broken functionality from Reusable Component)
SuiteName3: AccountManagement (By RunTestCase option, calling the broken functionality from Reusable Component)
```

AccountManagement suite is prepared by someone and the relevant Reusable component scripts give... I have imported Reusable component script in the Reusable component Suite.

Now When I am trying to Import AccountManagement suite, it is not properly taking the RunTestCase from Reusable component and it show unable to resolve classPath.

Can't we use the other Test Suite in soap UI again without mapping RunTest case.

Comment: Could not understand it better. If suite three has imported from other project, then how about relevant schemas / wsdl servies? are they present in current project? Can you provide reproducible generic project and share it via gist / git?

Comment: I am working  module1 say CustomerManagement Suite .. one more person is working on other suite..I am creating break up of each unit in Reusable component and creating functiona test case in Actual Suite. He does the same. we export each others reusable component and importing in to Reusbale component suite. But if we import our functional suite it is not properly referring RunTestCase and it says unable to resolve path..

Comment: Is it possible to create a dummy soapui project (post it github / gist) which can help to reproduce the issue?